# Buddypress Templates - how to customize user page?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

(in WordPress)I am wondering where to edit the BP templates - should I edit the core template files(in wp-content/plugins/buddypress) or is there a way to somehow make your own BuddyPress theme ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Start by adding a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) if you haven't done so already.
- Read the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/template-hierarchy/) link like slaFFik suggested.
- Add a directory 'buddypress' to your child theme.
- Copy the core template files you want to edit from wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/(XXX/YYY/)zzz.php into 
  themes/yourchildtheme/buddypress/(XXX/YYY/)zzz.php

If you edit the core files directly your changes could be lost when you update BP.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.  Something I didn't quite get from the notation above, until I did a bunch of trial and error is that one must create all the subdirectories in the path to your desired template under `/bp-legacy/buddypress/`  so if you want to modify `plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/members/registration.php` you need to copy it to `themes/yourtheme/buddypress/members/registration.php`  Just in case anyone else anyone gets confused like I did.

Comment: Thank you @neanderslob , this explanation was very helpful. I was confused by the name Buddypress and I was looking at the wrong folder. I didn't realize it was inside the legacy folder.

Answer (score 2):

Read this tutorial - [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/template-hierarchy/) (Single Member Pages)